# How long does it take to revert a dragon using the Fountain of Youth?

Tags: dragonvale

Because I apparently don't have better things to do, I've started to revert some of my dragons to babies using the Fountain of Youth.  I was surprised that it wasn't an instant action, and actually takes time like breeding or egg incubation.  So my question is - is the "revert" time for transforming an adult into a baby the same as breed/incubation time, or is it based on something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes 12 hours regardless of dragon; I've checked myself and got 12 hours and [the Wiki confirms](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Fountain_of_Youth). Making dragons older again also takes another 12 hours for any dragons.

Comment: Yeah, I have reverted bloom and panlongs and the a couple of others, its always 12 hours.

Comment: I have a screenshot as proof but Photostream is being slow so I don't have it yet

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info!  I was reverting a Cactus and I saw the 12 hours and thought - sheesh, I don't remember them taking that long.

Comment: @EBongo pretty sure it's just to give you extra incentive to use gems.